# How can i make this line of code cover every number in the 10 times table without coding every number

Tags: python

```
if count == 10 or count == 20 or count == 30 or count == 40 or count == 50 or count == 60 or count == 70 or count == 80 or count == 90:
            sleep(8)
```

i want this code to cover every number in the times 10 times table for ever, but i don't want to have to repeat the same code for ever to achieve this. Is there any way to code that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mod 10, e.g.

```
if count % 10 == 0:
    sleep(8)
```

This checks if `count` is evenly divisible by 10 and sleeps if it is. It doesn't matter how large `count` becomes.

Answer (score 1):

Use the modulo operator `%`.

```
if count%10 == 0:
    sleep(8)
```

You can also write

```
if not count%10:
    sleep(8)
```

but I find the first version easier to comprehend.

If you want to restrict the range for `count`, add another condition like this:

```
if (0 < count < 100) and count%10 == 0:
    sleep(8)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the modulo operator:
`if(x % 10 == 0):`

this will divide by 10 and return the remainer. if you enter a number dividable by 10, i.e the times ten table, it'll return 0. If you enter 11 for example it would return 1.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to check a value being in a given list, use the `in` operator

```
if count in (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90):
    sleep(8)

if count in range(10, 100, 10):
    sleep(8)
```

---

In you case math rules can be used, like the modulo operator

```
# for any multiple of 10, like -150 or 168730
if count%10 == 0:
    sleep(8)

# for multiple of 10, between 0 and 100
if (0 < count < 100) and count%10 == 0:
    sleep(8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the modulo operator "%" to determine whether the number is dividable or not by 10 in this manner (Modulo returns the reminder of the number it divides)

```
if count % 10 == 0:
    #do something
```

It will check if the last digit of the number is different or equal to 0

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `%` operator. It returns the remainder from division. Using the principle that if x is divisible by y with no remainder, x is a multiple of y, we can find out.

So:

```
num = 0
while True:
    if num % 10 == 0:
        time.sleep(8)
    else:
        pass
    num += 1
```